# click handler firing multiple times, unbind not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my jQuery click handler. It seems to be firing more than once when I click it. I tried using the .unbind method, but that broke my other jQuery. Why does this happen? I am attempting to build a calculator app and I want the numbers when clicked to be pushed to an array. The function works, it just does it too many times. Here is my javascript. Each button is a div with it's resepctive class, ie the "7" button is .seven.

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hidden > div").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
$("#hidden > div").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','black');
$("div.seven").click(function(){
    primary.push(7);
});
$("div.eight").click(function(){
    primary.push(8);
});
$("div.nine").click(function(){
    primary.push(9);
});
$("#.equals").click(function(){
alert(primary);
});
});
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because every time mouse enters to a `div` inside the `#hidden` element you are registering a click/mouseleave handler.

Under normal circumstances you should not register a event handler inside one.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var primary = [];
    $("#hidden > div").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
    $("#hidden > div").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
    });
    $("div.seven").click(function () {
        primary.push(7);
    });
    $("div.eight").click(function () {
        primary.push(8);
    });
    $("div.nine").click(function () {
        primary.push(9);
    });
    $("#.equals").click(function () {
        alert(primary);
    });
});
```